# Printing Input + Function Output with IO

Tags: io, scalaz

I wrote a simple function that (I intended) to print out (1) user input + (2) that input with "foobar" added to it:

```
import scalaz.effect.IO
import scalaz.effect.IO._

def simplePrint: (IO[Unit], IO[String]) = {
    val input = readLn
    val result = input.map(_ + "foobar")
    (input.flatMap(putStrLn), result)
}

def runExample: Unit = {
    val (in, result) = simplePrint
    println(">" + in.unsafePerformIO)
    println(result.unsafePerformIO)
}
```

Entering the `REPL`, I tested it out.

When I ran the `runExample` method, I typed "555", saw output, and then typed "1234".

```
scala> net.repl.Foo.runExample
555
>()
1234foobar
```

I had expected to type: "555", and then see:

```
>555
555foobar
```

How can I change the above method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're calling `unsafePerformIO` more than once, there's probably a problem with your program (and ideally you'd use `SafeApp` and not call it at all). Mixing untracked effects and `IO` is also unnecessarily messy. You want *all* of your effects to be sequenced, like this:

```
scala> val action = putStrLn(">") >> readLn.map(_ + "foobar") >>= putStrLn
action: scalaz.effect.IO[Unit] = scalaz.effect.IOFunctions$$anon$6@5a2ab2df

scala> action.unsafePerformIO
>
555foobar
```

This doesn't echo the characters while typing, though. I'm pretty sure I've written code to do that (with `getChar` and something like a hand-rolled `unfoldWhileM`), and I could try to dig it up later if you're interested.

Comment: `Mixing untracked effects...` - that means `println`, mutation, etc.? Trying it out in Haskell helped me to understand this correct approach: 
`ghci> do { i <- getLine; return (i, i ++ "foobar") }
1234 -- I typed this
("1234","1234foobar")`. Thank you

Comment: actually, I confused myself. It does not appear that `unsafePerformIO` needs to be called in Haskell.

Comment: `println` itself isn't a problem, but you've got it both outside of `IO` and inside `IO` (through `putStrLn`).

Comment: Yeah, Scalaz's `SafeApp` is basically an attempt to provide Scala with something like Haskell's `main`.

Comment: I'll take you up on that offer, please, Travis - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378195/printing-each-character-typed-w-scalaz, to learn how to spit out each character as it's typed.