# Printing Each Character Typed w/ Scalaz

Tags: haskell, scalaz

I'm trying to write the following Haskell function, but in Scala (using scalaz):

```
ghci>let f = do { x <- getChar; _ <- putChar(x); return () }
ghci>f -- then type '4'
44ghci>
```

Here's what I tried:

```
def showInput: IO[Unit] = for {
    c      <- getChar
    _      <- putChar(c)
} yield ()
```

Then I ran it:

```
scala> net.repl.Foo.showInput
res2: scalaz.effect.IO[Unit] = scalaz.effect.IOFunctions$$anon$6@73e3ae3a
```

After running the method, I typed `1234`. But, I had to press `enter` before the output (of `1`) showed up:

```
scala> res2.unsafePerformIO
1
```

How can I write the above scalaz function to behave identically to the Haskell function?

Comment: In ghci I also have to press `enter` (I'm on Windows)

Comment: That looks like a buffering issue; Not really related to haskell or scala. In haskell you can use `hSetBuffering` to adjust the buffering of a handle; I have no idea how to do it in java/scala though.